# Editor to work on GML files

Tags: software-recommendations, visualisation, xml, linux, gml

I am looking for a good way to work on GML files. At the moment I am using nXML or SGML mode for Emacs but I wouldnt mind having an IDE/Emacs mode/... that is more specialized on GML files and could possibly render changes in real time. Support for large files (>15 MB) would be a requirement.

I am running Linux (Ubuntu 13.04) so native programs would be prefered, but I don't mind if Windows programs are mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs will work fine, especially in nxml-mode if you have the relevant schema installed. But what nxml-mode lacks is the proper XML author controls which the older psgml-mode had: unfortunately psgml-mode won't work with schemas, only DTDs. SGML-mode will be useless for GML. There is also a good xslIDE-mode if you need to work on XSLT for transforming GML to other formats.

Real-time rendering isn't possible in Emacs AFAIK: you would need a separate rendering engine, and I'm not familiar with them. However, you could look at the work that has been done for LaTeX in AUCTeX, passivetex, activetex, and other near-real-time rendering of graphical output: perhaps there are ways to adapt the principle to using a GML rendering engine.

Beyond Emacs, there is nothing available free for editing XML at this scale. oXygen is an excellent general-purpose XML editor, and so are the dozen or so others, but I am not aware of any that have adaptations for GML (but it's not my field, so don't believe me).